# Maintaining Browser History when changing page content via Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, browser

As the title suggests I want to maintain browser history when I am changing the page via Ajax.

Now, each page has a corresponding action and/or URL Parameter so it is possible to navigate directly to each page via the URL but because I am changing the page using Ajax the browser's history and URL does change.

Think of Google Instant. Your not changing page between searches but the back/forward functionality of the browser is maintained. Any ideas how to do this (jQuery methods especially useful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try here: http://ajaxpatterns.org/Unique_URLs

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 introduces the pushState() function that allows for a manipulation of the browser history entries.
For jQuery, there is [jQuery BBQ: Back Button & Query Library](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) which looks very promising, although I have no personal experience with it.